# xorg high CPU usage (Ubuntu16.04 LTS)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, compiz, cpu

I am experiencing high CPU usage (around 20% using the top command) in idle when moving the cursor or when something changes on the screen (e.g. window is maximized, minimized, etc.). Additionally, compiz uses up to 30% CPU when moving e.g. a window. I am not sure if the desktop is rendered with CPU or GPU because the GPU also shows approx. 3% usage when shifting windows in idle.

I am using:

- CPU: Intel i56600 Skylake
- GPU: Nvidia GTX960 with driver version 367.57 (installed with additional drivers tool)
- Unity desktop

I already tried:

- using the standard Nouveau driver
- using another login profile
- using the gnome desktop
- changing the text fonts in the profile settings
- disabling VBlank synchronization in compiz settings manager

but the problem remains. I would be happy if somebody has an idea what to do...

Comment: 384.111 still has the same problem.  Answer deleted.